# How to update a string in middle of it in sql which was repeated twice

Tags: sql

If we have a string like below:

```
//aaaaa/bbbb/ccccc//ddddd/e/fgh.docx
```

I want to remove the second occurrence of '`//`'.

Please suggest me a sql statement to update this existing string by removing second occurrence of this '//'.

Assume the above string is there in column `file_path`, and having unique id associated with it in a row like

```
doc_id      file_path    
1           //aaaaa/bbbb/ccccc//ddddd/e/fgh.docx
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REPLACE` function.

Something like:

```
SELECT '/' + REPLACE(file_path, '//', '/') FROM <table>
```

It would work in SQL Server. Check for similar function in your RDBMS.

Comment: Can I know how it will take second occurrence of "//" from your query.

Comment: @SUNANDCH it will replace all occurences of '//' with '/'. So in essence '//aaaaa/bbbb/ccccc//ddddd/e/fgh.docx' will become '/aaaaa/bbbb/ccccc/ddddd/e/fgh.docx'. Since it will result in one '/' missing just in the beginning of string I added '/' i.e. '/' + '/aaaaa/bbbb/ccccc/ddddd/e/fgh.docx'.

Comment: Great bro understood thank you for making it clear :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
UPDATE <Table Name>
SET file_path = CONCAT('/', REPLACE(file_path, '//', '/'))
WHERE doc_id = 1
```

Comment: Important to mention that CONCAT (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) only works for SQL Server 2012 and up. Also, you'll have to remove the space in your first string for this to produce correct results.

Comment: according to CONCAT operator , its supported by most of RDBMS

Comment: Can you explain what does this exactly doing CONCAT('/', REPLACE(file_path, '//', '/')) @Mohammad

Comment: "Replace" will change all // to / then "CONCAT" will add new / @the beginning

Comment: if my comment was helpful , please make the answer helpful to help others see the answer :)

Comment: But how it is taking second occurrence from your query ?
There are two '//' occurrences how is it going to second occurrence..

Comment: @Jens: that version of `concat()` will also work for Postgres, Oracle or MySQL

Comment: @SUNANDCH it is not only processing the second occurance. It is replacing both. That's why an extra '/' is added to the result using CONCAT. It avoids the issue of finding the second '/'.

@ MohammadHanafy : Agreed, I tend to focus on SQL Server too much :)

Comment: It is not replacing first occurrence it is replacing second occurrence. So I am having doubt how it is leaving first "//" and replacing second "//" with this '/' with that query ??@MohammadHanafy @Jens

Comment: @SUNANDCH Yes, it is. But the final result adds another / in front of the replaced string result. Try removing concat and you'll understand better.

Comment: Which dbms is this product specific answer for?

Comment: Great bro understood thank you for making it clear @Jens